# How to modify the form fiels values in a GHL website?

Tags: nuxt.js

I developed a website using GoHighLevel web builder. The survey form is embedded into it. Using JavaScript/jQuery I can manipulate all of the elements. The generated value is displayed in the target input field. However, it keeps resetting to empty values on clicking previous pages and on form submission.

It seems GHL is using Nuxt.